# Swift 4 map a dictionary with [String:[Object]] more efficiently

Tags: swift, swift4

I am reading an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[Group(id:"g001", name:"Group 1", projects:[Project(id:"p001", name:"Project 1"), Project(id:"p002", name:"Project 2")]), Group(id:"g002", name:"Group 2", projects:[Project(id:"p003", name:"Project 3")])]
```

Right now, I am using two for-loops to get to the `projects`, and then adding them to the dictionary like this:

```
var dictionary: Dictionary = [String: [Project]]()
for group in groups{
  let groupId = group.id
  for project in group.projects {
      dictionary[groupId, default: []].append(project)
  }
}
```

It works, but it seems like with Swift 4 it can be done more efficiently, and more quickly. What is the best way to use map or reduce with this type of array and dictionary?

Comment: Why not `dictionary[group.id] = group.projects`? Just eliminate the inner `for` loop

Comment: What do you mean by "reading" the array?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that group id is unique:

```
var dictionary = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: groups.map{($0.id, $0.projects)})
```